# GridBagLayout component not filling space as it should

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm making a program that uses lots of different compenents, so I've started using a GridBagLayout for it. It's working great, but when I run the program I get this:

[Picture of current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE3fp.png)

It should be putting the right-most list object directly up against the rest of the objects, and filling the entire width of the screen. Not sure why it isn't. Here's a short copy of the relevant code (I put them all into one class for simplicity should you decide to run it.):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Example extends JFrame{
    private Character me;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Example();
    }

    public Example(){
        add(new CharacterDisplay(new Character()));
        setSize(600,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Character{
        public ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
        public Character(){
            notes.add("A");
            notes.add("few");
            notes.add("notes");
        }
    }

    private class CharacterDisplay extends JPanel{
        public CharacterDisplay(Character myself){
            me = myself;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            JTextArea filler = new JTextArea();
            c.gridx  = 0;
            c.weightx = 1;
            c.weighty = 1;
            c.gridheight = 11;
            c.gridwidth = 6;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(filler,c);

            c.gridy = 0;
            c.gridx = 6;
            c.weightx = 1;
            c.weighty = 1;
            c.gridheight = 11;
            c.gridwidth = 3;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new NoteBox(), c);
        }
    }

    private class NoteBox extends JPanel{
        private int currentNotes = 0;
        private JList<String> listContainer;
        private JTextField addNoteField = new JTextField();
        private JButton removalButton = new JButton("Remove Selected Notes");
        private JScrollPane listScroll;
        public NoteBox(){
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            addNoteField.setText("Add a note here");
            addNoteField.addActionListener(e -> {
                me.notes.add(addNoteField.getText()); 
                repaint();});
            String[] model = new String[me.notes.size()];
            model = me.notes.toArray(model);
            listContainer = new JList<String>(model);
            removalButton.addActionListener(e -> remove(listContainer.getSelectedIndices()));
            listScroll = new JScrollPane(listContainer);
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridwidth = 3;
            c.weighty = 0;
            add(addNoteField, c);
            c.weighty = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridheight = 9;
            add(listScroll, c);
            c.weighty = 0;
            c.gridy = 10;
            add(removalButton, c);
        }

        public void remove(int[] indices){
            //Go backward to avoid shifting indices of the next ones to remove;
            for(int i = indices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                me.notes.remove(indices[i]);
            }
            repaint();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            String[] model = new String[me.notes.size()];
            model = me.notes.toArray(model);
            listContainer.setListData(model);
        }
    }
}
```

I included all of the NoteBox class because it's the one that's malfunctioning and I figured it was the most relevant.

Comment: Don't update the `listContainer` in the `paintComponent method, that's going to cause other issues

Comment: Have you tried using `weightx = 1` for the `listScroll`?

Comment: Using weightx = 1 fixed it entirely. I spent over half an hour looking over that trying to find it, and just completely skimmed over that each time. I appreciate the help. Also, I'll stop updating 'listContainer' in 'paintComponent' - however what causes that to make issues, out of curiosity?

Also, thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @MatthewWhitlock I strongly recommend that you post an answer to your question describing how you solved it. You'll be able to subsequently mark the question as solved by accepting your own answer after a few days. Simply writing "solved" in the title does not prevent it from appearing as unsolved in search results and does not assist the community.

Comment: paintComponent is called automagically by the API, most of the time without you knowing or requesting it, updating the JList inside it could trigger new repaints, which could cause the EDT to cycle uncontrollably, making it impossible to interact with your ui and/or consume all your cpu cycles, generally speaking, paint is for painting the current state of your ui, it should never modify or update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to put weightx = 1 within my NoteBox inner class, as suggested by MadProgrammer. This fixed the issue entirely, I'm just writing this to formally mark the answer as solved.